# Rライブラリインストール方法（tabplot)

Tags: r

Rで表記のライブラリをインストールしようとすると、

```
install.packages('tabplot')
```

下記のようなエラーが出てきました。

```
Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/●●●●/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

Rtoolsをインストールする必要があると書いてあるので、インストールしてみましたが、インストール後にPATHを通す必要があるようなのですが方法が分からず・・ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: Users の次の ●●●● の部分は 全角だったり スペースが入ったりしてませんか？

Comment: ●●●●の部分は半角数字のみです。

Answer (score 0):

WindowsのPATHはコントロールパネルの「システムのプロパティ」にある「環境変数…」から変更できます。ここにRToolsをインストールした場所を追記してみてください。

https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1805/11/news035.html にて詳しい方法が解説されています。Windows 10でなくとも同じようなステップで設定できたと思います。